# Make Enter select cells in a different order in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that looks like this
[image: Excel product card template]

The requirement is to go through all columns using only Enter key.

So far, when the selection gets to A3:A12 over which the ActiveX Image sits, after user selects an image, I call `ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Select` which selects the B3:D3 cell.

Now, when i press Enter, I expect to land on B4, but it goes to A13.
I also tried `ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Select` and Enter after that goes back to A3:A12 with the image on top.

Is there any pattern I am missing, or is this just excel being difficult to deal with?

I also tried `Application.OnKey "~", "ChangeCell"` in hopes that i could change the behavior of Enter altogether, but i get

> Cannot run the macro "path/to/my/file"!ChangeCell the macro may not be
>   available in this workbook

each time I press Enter. (Yes I enabled the `Trust access to the VBA project object model`.)

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Edit: Here is the relevant part of the code. (It's my first time in VBA)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    address = Target.address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    If address = "A3:A12" Then
        ChangeImage
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "~", "ChangeCell"
End Sub

Sub ChangeCell()
    MsgBox ("Ay")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key that will work is the big one in the middle of your keyboard. Write this in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "~"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "KeepOnMoving"
End Sub
```

---

And then write this in a module:

```
Public Sub KeepOnMoving()
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

You can "reset" the `ActiveCell`, once you go to column `K` (for example):

```
Public Sub KeepOnMoving()        
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Activate        
    If ActiveCell.Column = Range("K1").Column Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(, -1 * Range("K1").Column + 1).Activate
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have a problem binding {Enter} or "~". But my Sub doesn't get called and instead i get that "Cannot run the macro "path/to/my/file"!ChangeCell the macro may not be available in this workbook" only in Czech

Comment: @Tojik - what would happen if you restart your PC and you make sure that you have only one Excel opened? Would it work? (It seems that you are trying to access a macro on a different Workbook, am I right?

Comment: The bind as well as my Sub is inside the worksheet macro file, will try placing ChangeCell inside the workbook file. Also restarted my PC as you suggested.

Comment: @Tojik - make `KeepOnMoving` public and put it into a module.

Comment: Oh yeah you said module, sorry... Ok so Subs outside modules (inside sheets and workbooks) are invisible for things using the "VBA project object model". Thank you

Comment: Any idea why Enter does those seemingly random jumps in the first part of my question?